# Android onActivityResult() always return null

Tags: android

I am trying to return a result from a child activity to the parent activity.
This is my code in the parent activity

```
        private val REQUEST_CODE = 1       
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       startActivityForResult(Intent(this,DescriptionActivity::class.java).apply{
                    putExtra("EXTRA_FOOD_NAME", foodName)
                    putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE", image)
                    putExtra("EXTRA_FOOD_DESC", foodDesc)
                },REQUEST_CODE) 
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE &&
                resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
//It is null when I check it inside here
            val orderedFood = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ORDER")
            current_oreder.add(orderedFood)

        }

    }
```

Child activity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {   
val foodName = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_FOOD_NAME")
        btnAddToOrder.setOnClickListener{addToOrder(foodName)}
    }

private fun addToOrder(foodName:String?)
    {
        val orderIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra("EXTRA_ORDER", foodName)
        }
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, orderIntent)
        finish()
    }
```

I checked if the child activity's foodName variable has a null value but it has the correct value. It changes to null when I return it to the parent activity. I tried solutions I found on the internet but it didn't work. Can anyone fix this issue?

Comment: Did you mean to write? `data.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ORDER")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Which part are you talking about?

Comment: This line `val orderedFood = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ORDER")` as intent is the activities intent, not the result Intent which here is called `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used in the onActivityResult method：

```
data?.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ORDER")
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE &&
                resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
//It is null when I check it inside here
            val orderedFood = data?.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ORDER")
            current_oreder.add(orderedFood)
        }
    }
```